# PHP isset($_POST[]) won't trigger inside JQuery Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am having trouble getting the PHP for my registration form to work after I moved the forum to a JQuery Modal. Test 1 echos but Test 2 won't. Can anyone help? This is the header file for every page in my website. When this code is used on a regular page and not in modals it works. The php connection is initialized in the index.php file.

```
<?php
echo "test 1<br>";

$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$fn = "";
$ln = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$pswrd = "";
$pswrd2 = "";
$d = "";
$u_check = "";

$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswrd = strip_tags(@$_POST['pw']);
$pswrd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['pw2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d");

$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");
$check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
        echo " test 2";
        if($fn&&$ln){
            if($em == $em2){
                if($pswrd == $pswrd2){
                    if($check == 0){
                        $pswrd = md5($pswrd);
                        $pswrd2 = md5($pswrd2);
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$fn', '$ln', '$em', '$pswrd', '$d', '0')");
                        die("<h1>Registrastion Successful</h1>");
                    }                       }
                    else echo "<p id = 'regerror'>Email is already registered by a different user.</p>";
                }
                else echo "<p id = 'regerror'>Passwords do not match.</p>";
            }
            else echo "<p id = 'regerror'>Emails do not match.</p>";
        }
    else echo "<p id = 'regerror'>Please fill out all fields.</p>";
}
?>
<header id="header">
    <div id="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <ul id="top-info">
                        <li>Phone: </li>
                        <li>Email: </li>

                    </ul>
                    <ul id="top-buttons">
                        <?php 
                        if($_SESSION['user_email'] == ""){
                            echo "<li><a href='#login' data-toggle='modal'><i class='fa fa-sign-in'></i> Login</a></li>
                                  <li class='divider'></li>
                                  <li><a href='#register' data-toggle='modal'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> Register</a></li>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<li>Welcome, <a href='#'>".$_SESSION['user_fname']." ".$_SESSION['user_lname']."</a> - <a href = 'http://urbanares.com/logout/index.php'>log out</a></li>";
                        }?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sticky-wrapper"><div id="nav-section" class="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <a href="http://urbanares.com/landing/index.php" class="nav-logo"><img src="../list_property/list_property_files/logo_transparent.png" alt="UrbanaRE Logo"></a>

                    <!-- BEGIN MAIN MENU -->
                        <nav class="navbar">
                        <button id="nav-mobile-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="http://urbanares.com/property_info/index.php?id=59">Buy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://urbanares.com/list_property">Sell</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Rent</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Seminars</a></li>
                            <!--<li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>-->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- END MAIN MENU -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--LOGIN MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" id="login" role="dialogue">
        <div class="modal-dialogue">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="#" method="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="email address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="password">
                        </div>
                        <!-- END ADDRESS FORM -->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class = "btn btn-warning" data-dismiss = "modal">Login</a><a class = "btn btn-warning" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--REGISTER MODAL -->

<div class="modal fade col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" id="register" role="dialogue">
    <div class="modal-dialogue">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Register</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12"><br></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Confirm Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pw" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pw2" placeholder="Re-type Password">
                    </div>

                        <!-- END ADDRESS FORM -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class = "btn btn-warning" name="reg">Sign Up</button><a class = "btn btn-warning" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please dont use mysql_* function and `strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);` isnt way to validate Request

Comment: that's not the issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a *form* with method "POST". Make sure you use a *button* with type="submit" to send a data. **Don't Use a Hyperlink**

Change this code :

```
<a href="#" class = "btn btn-warning" name="reg">Sign Up</button>
```

to :

```
<button type="submit" class = "btn btn-warning" name="reg" value="reg">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: That worked up my question and I will up your answer!

Comment: Sorry I was a little late